# Dlib apply self trained detector to video (mmod_dnn)

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

Im trying to track in video a self trained cat detector using the mmod_dnn model in Dlib. I have trained my own network using the [dnn_mmod_train_find_cars_example](http://dlib.net/dnn_mmod_train_find_cars_ex.cpp.html) form the [blog post](http://blog.dlib.net/2017/08/vehicle-detection-with-dlib-195_27.html). It works well to detect cats in images using the [dnn_mmod_face_detector](http://dlib.net/dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex.cpp.html) example, but I wish to track the cat in video. I have tried to use the [webcam_face_pose](http://dlib.net/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.html) example as a starting point, but I cant seem to figure out how to apply my own network instead of the face detector. Any help is much appriciated.

code:

```
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlib/dnn.h>
#include <dlib/data_io.h>
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

// network ----------------------
template <long num_filters, typename SUBNET> using con5d = con<num_filters, 
5, 5, 2, 2, SUBNET>;
template <long num_filters, typename SUBNET> using con5 = con<num_filters, 
5, 5, 1, 1, SUBNET>;
template <typename SUBNET> using downsampler = relu<bn_con<con5d<32, 
relu<bn_con<con5d<32, relu<bn_con<con5d<16, SUBNET>>>>>>>>>;
template <typename SUBNET> using rcon5 = relu<bn_con<con5<55, SUBNET>>>;
using net_type = loss_mmod<con<1, 9, 9, 1, 1, rcon5<rcon5<rcon5<downsampler<input_rgb_image_pyramid<pyramid_down<6>>>>>>>>;
----------------------------------

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cv::VideoCapture cap("cat.avi");
        if (!cap.isOpened())
        {
            cerr << "Unable to connect to camera" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        image_window win;
        net_type net;
        deserialize("cat_detector.dat") >> net;

        // Grab and process frames until the main window is closed by the user.
        while(!win.is_closed())
        {
            // Grab a frame
            cv::Mat temp;
            if (!cap.read(temp))
            {
                break;
            }

            cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(temp);

            // This is where I get an error (error message below):
            std::vector<rectangle> dets = net(cimg);
                -------------------

            // Display it all on the screen
            win.clear_overlay();
            win.set_image(temp);
            win.add_overlay(dets, rgb_pixel(255, 0, 0));
        }
    }
    catch(serialization_error& e)
    {
        cout << endl << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch(exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

error : `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::vector<std::vector<dlib::mmod_rect,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>' to 'std::vector<dlib::rectangle,std::allocator<_Ty>>'`

I seem to have the wrong vector type, even though the [webcam_face_pose](http://dlib.net/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.html) example uses this vector, except I dont use the face model in the example. I have also tried `std::vector<full_object_detection>` as  in the example, but I dont think I understand how to apply my own network correctly. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble with this, I've been working on a similar problem and found some solutions.

The main problem here is that for the mmod_dnn models, `net(cimg)` does not return a vector of rectangles. It returns something like this: `vector<mmod_rect>` or `vector<vector<mmod_rect>>`, depending on whether you gave it a single image or multiple images. The [face detector example code](http://dlib.net/dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex.cpp.html) you linked uses `auto dets = net(img)`. You'll then have to convert them to dlib rectangles to try to work out pose.

Other problems you may run into is that the mmod_dnn network takes a `matrix<rgb_pixel>` or `vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>>` type, so you'll have to convert to those. Dlib has some functions to help there:

```
cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(temp);
matrix<rgb_pixel> matrix;
assign_image(matrix, cimg)
```